# How to set text axis distance in R plot, without using 'title' and 'mtext'?

Tags: r, plot, text, axis

I'm putting togheter 15 plots with `par`function.
The problem is that I can't set the title distance from the top axis of the plots.
Infact each plot have the title too near to the top axis.

I'm trying to use the `mar`argument in `par` function, but it dosen't work. But for example `cex.main` argument for the title size works.
How can I set the title distance from the top axis?

I already read about the use of `title` or `mtext`functions, but I have to avoid to use them, because I'm using a `for` loop on the plot line, in order to plot the 15 variables with the same line and put them togheter with 'par' function.
I already tried, if I use `title` or `mtext` to set title text, they works only for the last plot, the last of the loop. Maybe there is a way to use `title` or `mtext` with the loop on the plot, but I don't know how.
I hope you understand the problem.

How appear titles on the top axis
[image: How appear titles on the top axis]

Here part of the dataset:
Because the final dataset is too huge to share, I share with you also a little part of the code needed to reproduce the final dataset.

Initial dataset

```
structure(c(-0.322237443892839, 0.161789861737245, -0.282562534820935, 
-0.25424683208082, -0.259238297819659, -0.588115307575363, -0.170089596361983, 
0.133764670772236, -0.136543241076998, -0.132742895064731, -0.453971753822024, 
-0.0484711446567853, -0.27953600157388, -0.468459003414809, -0.255322689071146, 
0.217651987645887, 0.221472492114085, -0.401231971742935, 0.157037417398378, 
0.384059018253568, 0.171821179673259, 0.239552559816231, -0.278429725475918, 
-0.420437810679651, -0.215328948866159, -0.287310214334936, -0.275739086804379, 
0.403972971818474, 0.274743078665728, 0.246605637402898, 0.267120005514042, 
0.276023917133903, -0.252799241134603, 0.092373911821187, 0.235510208843125, 
-0.605062748251485, -0.345240248134856, 0.362487256397189, -0.180711585509626, 
-0.223826280434943, -0.0525631620091461, 0.338460608474323, 0.224583788801295, 
0.536214131347007, 0.133547702598715, -0.333334973012602, 0.305004985920743, 
0.470781195933839, 1.22134562554239, 1.56844544565986, 0.772580607298005, 
-0.0199651879630767, 1.46266479689702, 0.0966653263169418, -0.864168809400028, 
-0.864179388471044, -0.864177877175184, -0.864180899766903, -0.864176365879325, 
-0.8641884562462, -1.75348221807367, -1.83784316300396, -1.87211479688189, 
-1.93538550557961, -2.07774460014948, -2.07774460014948, -1.19675824922347, 
-1.20079873516416, -1.18246979705117, -1.19228273612708, -1.22456058732531, 
-1.23721762021624, -0.0285485437185394, 0.580463137050019, 0.925574527286982, 
0.534238499345519, 0.556521230080963, 0.51386899109342, -1.0175436256117, 
-1.0175436256117, -1.0175436256117, -1.0175436256117, -1.0175436256117, 
-1.0175436256117, -1.3369771887616, -1.3369771887616, -1.3369771887616, 
-1.3369771887616, -1.3369771887616, -1.3369771887616), .Dim = c(6L, 
15L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), c("mz33_fluxmax", 
"mz45_fluxmax", "mz47_fluxmax", "mz59_fluxmax", "mz61_fluxmax", 
"mz69_fluxmax", "mz99_fluxmax", "mz101_fluxmax", "mz137_fluxmax", 
"PAR", "Tair", "VPD", "NEE", "AGB", "GAI")))
```

Part of the code to reproduce the final dataset

```
cioffisom1=as.matrix(scale(cioffisom1))
som_grid <- somgrid(xdim = 40, ydim=40, topo="rectangular")
som_model <- som(cioffisom1, 
                 grid=som_grid, 
                 rlen=1000, 
                 alpha=c(0.05,0.01), 
                 keep.data = TRUE)
```

Here part of the code that I already tried:

```
par(mar=c(5,4,6,2)+0.1,mfcol = c(3, 5),cex.main=2)

for (i in 1:15)

plot(som_model, type = "property", property = getCodes(som_model[,i],
main=colnames(getCodes(som_model))[i],palette.name=coolBlueHotRed)
```

Comment: i'm not understanding why you can't use `title(..., line = x)` because of a for loop, please add your code

Comment: I added code and dataset

Comment: I can't use `title` and for loop in the right way, but It doesn't mean that is not possible. I don't know how.

Comment: are you using brackets in your loop? `for (i in 1:15) {plot(...); title(...)}`

Comment: Great. It works, thanks!